# Prevent Magento from overwriting URL key

Tags: url, url-key

I have the following problem with my products in Magento. 
Once I upload products and save them initially the URL key field stays empty and the product just gets a URL like

`www.mysite.com/SKU`

However once I change something in the product and save it again it changes the URL to

```
www.mysite.com/Product-title
```

And it also writes the product name in the URL key.
Is there a way I can prevent this from happening?

It seems weird that this happens all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL Key, if you do not specify it is generated automatically based on the product name. It sounds like this is what is happening here.

The default process would be to strip out spaces and replace it with - based on the product name.

You can manually set the url key, there is a field for it in the product management page. If you set this to what you want it to be instead of blank, or what it currently is (i.e. product-name) and save (remember to clear cache) it should then give you the url in the exact format you want.

Usually, the URL Key field is in the General Tab of the Product Editor towards the bottom.

Comment: Can i specify that it is generated automatically using the ISBN? I know that there is the field but when importing my products it is empty after modifying the products it changes it from the original url with SKU to url with title

Comment: If you want to have it generate in a custom way, you would need to generate a module that would override the core functionality to achieve that.

Comment: Do you know if there is another way of doing this then manually adding these URL keys?